# PHP: Adding vars at runtime

Tags: php, oop, class

Hey!
I have a local test server on my machine and my production server.
Instead of constantly editing my database credentials I want to include a db.php file that looks like this:

```
<?php

var $hostt = "localhost";
var $db_database = "testdb";
var $db_username = "root";
var $db_password= "";
?>
```

but when I try including it like this:

```
<?php

class testme{

include_once "db.php";

...
```

It refuses to work and spits out:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE_ONCE, expecting T_FUNCTION in**

How can I get it to work the way I want to? Is it possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks!
R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't execute an include statement outside of either the global scope or a function scope.

Move the include above your class declaration.

If you need access to those configuration options inside your class, try something like this.

```
// db.php

return array('host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'testdb', etc);

// inside class function

$db_config = require 'db.php';
```

If you need it from many functions within the class. Set a class variable within your constructor:

```
class Something {

     public $config;

     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->config = require 'db.php';
     }

}
```

Comment: I have many functions in the class, some use the DB but most dont... thats why I need this outside the function. Possible?

Comment: The easiest solution may be to add it within __construct and call it globally. Basically, you'll need include_once in every function you'd need the DB values, if you don't do it globally. The memory overhead shouldn't be hard. I'd suggest global.